# How does SQL Server store a composite primary key?

Tags: sql-server, primary-key, storage

The limit of my understanding how a database stores a primary key is a btree based on the clustered key with each node storing the rest of the columns.

I have not updated this understanding since university last century and would love to know how SQL Server stores a composite primary key compared to a single primary key.

Can anyone help point me to some detail on this?

Comment: I don't have time to give a proper answer now but will just mention that there are actually 3 different possibilities to consider here (1) The PK is the clustered index (2) The PK is a non clustered index on a heap (3) The PK is a non clustered index on a table with another clustered index.

Comment: So the clustered index is the storage, not the PK. I guess I had not think of these items as synonymous anymore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A composite key is exactly the same as a ordinary, single column, key, but is longer and composed of multiple values. Consider you have a B-Tree on a single column, say A. The non-leaf pages contains slots with values of A column, and pointers to leaf-pages. The leaf pages contain slots with the column A values (the key), followed by all the other columns of the row. A composite key is exactly the same, but the values in the slots will be the composite values, in the order they are declared in the key.

There is a great description of the internals of a SQL Server data page at [Anatomy of a Page](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/Inside-the-Storage-Engine-Anatomy-of-a-page.aspx). Also, the Chapter 6 from Kelan Delaney's old SQL 7.0 book is available online on Technet: [Tables](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917720.aspx#EHAA). Is still a great resource, the basics still apply to SQL 2008 R2 (things that are changed are mostly around max types and compression settings, but the bulk of info is still valid).